# lftp whiptail progress bar

Tags: debian, lftp, whiptail

I am using the following command in a bash script to download files from an ftp server. This command uses the -v option which shows the name of each file being downloaded.

```
/usr/bin/lftp ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppass@$ftphost -e "$ftpsettings ;
  mirror -v -e $remotemedia $localmedia ; quit"
```

I need to modify the script, to display a progress bar using whiptail, to show the download progress. This is the progress bar, but I don't know how to make it read the lftp download progress.

```
{
    for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=5)); do
        sleep 0.1
        echo $i
    done
} | whiptail --gauge "Downloading file $name..." 6 50 0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a percentage you need to know the total number of files.
You can get this from an `ls -R` inside another `lftp`, starting at the same directory as your `mirror` command. I subtracted 2 for "." and ".." in the listing.

```
let total=$(lftp "ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppass@$ftphost" -e "$ftpsettings ;
   ls -R $remotemedia; quit" | wc -l)-2
```

You can then read each line output from lftp, and for those beginning "Transferring" you can increment a line counter, calculate the percentage, and use the "XXX" input style that `--gauge` accepts (XXX, a percent, a title, XXX).

```
lftp "ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppass@$ftphost" -e "$ftpsettings ;
  mirror -v -e $remotemedia $localmedia ; quit" |

while read word word2 filename
do    if [ "$word" = Transferring ]
      then let count=count+1
           let percent=count*100/total
           echo -e "XXX\n$percent\nDownloading $filename\nXXX"
      fi
done |
whiptail --title lftp --gauge progress 10 60 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative, which in my humble opinion works better than whiptail, the beloved tqdm. Tqdm can be installed through pip or Yiur package manager of choice.

To use it we follow the same idea: first get the number of files, then echo the iteration number in the loop and pipe it all to tqdm

```
let total=$(lftp "ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppass@$ftphost" -e "$ftpsettings ;
   ls -R $remotemedia; quit" | wc -l)-2

lftp ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppass@$ftphost -e "$ftpsettings ;
  mirror -v -e $remotemedia $localmedia ; quit" |

while read word word2 filename
do    if [ "$word" = Transferring ]
      then let count=count+1
           echo "$count" 
      fi
done | tqdm --total $total
```