# How to show a progress bar for lftp script for newer version of lftp in 2020?

Tags: shell-script, terminal, ftp, lftp, whiptail

I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287186/29193) question and its answer, but they do not answer my question.

The shell script is this:

```bsh
let total=$(lftp -f lftp-script-count.txt | wc -l)-2

lftp -f lftp-script.txt |

while read word word2 filename
do
    if [ "$word" = Transferring ]
    then let count=count+1
         let percent=count*100/total
         echo -e "XXX\n$percent\nDownloading $filename\nXXX"
    fi
done |

whiptail --title lftp --gauge progress 10 60 0
```

The **lftp-scrip-count.txt** lftp script works well:

```
debug 10
set ssl:verify-certificate no
open ...
user ... ...
cd ...
ls -R .
```

The **lftp-scrip-count.txt** lftp script works slow (but works for sure although I would love it to work faster) and the progress does not get to whiptail:

```
set ssl:verify-certificate no
open ...
user ...
cd ...
mirror -P=10 . lftp-works --exclude-glob=node_modules
quit
```

The result is that the progress bar is shown but remains at 0% till the end although it got to download the entire 251MB. If I resize the terminal window the whiptail screen does not get repainted.

When it reaches the end of the download, the progress bar window disappears well.

It seems to me that the procent shown by the simple `lftp -f lftp-script.txt` is not global. The output of this command contains, besides the percent, things like this:

- Waiting for response...
- Receiving data/TLS
- Making data connection...
- Receiving data...

Example:

[image: screenshot]

**My question is:** How can I get the progress bar to show the progress well?

Is there another CLI FTP client that shows the progress and is good for my requirements as seen in the lftp scripts shown above?

Thank you.

## Update 1

There are 2 remaining issues:

1. It would be great if I could show the progress of the operation relative to the total number of files that will be copied, not all the files available to be copied, because I use `--only-newer`.
2. Keeping (1) in mind, it would be interesting to find out why with `--only-newer` it has the same speed like without it, when the directory is already completely downloaded. If I could make the process faster it would be great.

Comment: You're missing the `|` at the end of the `lftp` command: `lftp "ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppass@$ftphost" -e "$ftpsettings ;
  mirror -v -e $remotemedia $localmedia ; quit" |`, which connects it to the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it. Now it is like on my computer.

Comment: Your mirror command uses different options (`-v` is missing, at least). Have you tried using the same options as in the linked post?

Comment: Thank you. With `-v` everything works well, except the speed... With FileZilla it worked faster when selecting to overwrite files only if they are newer. What could be the cause? I started using `--only-newer` but it still is slower with 1-2 minutes in plus when compared to FileZilla.